# How to move whole layout move up when soft keyboard open in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move my layout which has several views in it so when user touch edit text
then keyboard open and my layout widget goes up.
I have even use code in manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
then android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" 
    Nothing work so please help me
    Here is my xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/theme_color"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLAyoutId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/osmosis_label" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_screen_username_editText1"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/username_editbox_text"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_screen_password_editText2"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_screen_username_editText1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_screen_username_editText1"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/password_editbox_text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/login_layout" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login_screen_submit_button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_screen_password_editText2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/log_in"
                android:text="Login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_screen_submit_button1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/registered_textview_id"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @ Ashutosh Bansaldid you found the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: This link may be helpful to you. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on][1]

see the accepted answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your oncreate.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```