# Workaround for adjustresize and adjustpan bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

I'm looking for a workaround this issue. I've looked at:

[adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

[Adjust layout when soft keyboard is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on)

[setSoftInputMode() and addFlags()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/T193nVgXDSA/O6UZmDqskFYJ)

and tried putting in:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Where I flip the flags for fullscreen when the keyboard comes up, but it doesn't seem to work.

My layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_btn"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/post_bar"
        android:divider="@drawable/grey_divider"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/status_gradient" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_text_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_text_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/post_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_btn_post"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_btn_post"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout also sits inside a horizontal scroll view with menus on either side of this main layout.

How could I make the main page resize such that the edittext box is on top of the keyboard when it appears?

Edit: If I take it out of the horizontalscrollview I'm using, it works, but since I'm using it to display my menus, I need a solution that works with them in there.
[Link to HorizontalScrollView implementation I'm using](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo)

-Thanks

Comment: Where is the EditText now?  Is it where the soft keyboard would be shown?  What is your current softInputMode?

Comment: The EditText I'm referring to is the one with id post_text.  It is at the bottom of the page after the listview and is covered by the keyboard when focused.  I've tried several different input modes including the combinations of stateVisible, stateHidden, adjustPan, adjustResize.

Comment: Hmmmm, very strange.  When I put that EditText in there with no other types of modification other than changing it to being laid out to the left/right of left_text_btn and right_text_btn everything worked swimmingly.  What happens when you pull the layout out of the ScrollView?

Comment: It actually works fine when I take it out of the HorizontalScrollView, which is great, however since the HSV is how I'm displaying the menus it's not going to work as a fix.  The specific implementation of the HorizontalScrollView I'm using is from this github project for scrolling side menus. I'll add this link to the original post.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using that specific HorizontalScrollView instead of using the default Android one?  What happens if you just use a normal HorizontalScrollView?