# Android- how to autoscroll when keyboard is up

Tags: android, xml, layout, scroll, keyboard

I've this big problem: when i click on edittext and the keyboard is up, the keyboard covers the button. I've searched the solution around the web but adjustresize, adjustpan don't work. I've tried also to use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);` but doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/sfondo3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
     >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="Inserisci un Nickname:"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:text="Accedi" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logox" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declare `windowSoftInputMode` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as following. It fill force activity to adjust its size when keyboard is shown.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityName"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

If this doesn't help, you might want to implement a more complex solution suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on).