# Cancel EditText input --> recreate MainActivity (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my mainactivity, I have several radiobuttons (2 groups), a 'go' button and on the bottom of the screen an EditText field.

When a user selects the EditText field, the keyboard pops up. The first thing I want is that the 'go' button **remains** and that the 2 radiogroups containing multiple radiobuttons **disappear**. That way, the screen layout remains as simple as possible.

Also, when the user cancels the EditText input (pressing back button on device), I would like the MainActivity (screen with all buttons and the edittextfield) to reappear.

The first part works when I setVisibility of the RadioGroups to View.INVISIBLE within the onClick listener of the EditText field.

However, when a user cancels input in the EditText field (keyboard disappears) the layout remains in that specific view: only the 'go' button & edittextfield are visible on the screen.

How can I handle the cancel/back button of the device when using an EditText field and make it restart an activity or reappear previously hidden layout elements?

Comment: Would be better if you share some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this effect:

- Override the `android:configChanges` in the Manifest in order to handle the keyboard visible/hidden event yourself, as discussed in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) dev guide.
- Implement a custom layout that will listen for keyboard visibility changes and will allow you to make changes to your UI, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on) SO question