# ScrollView compress my layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I have made a layout for login in a demo application,and need to scroll the layout when soft keyboard open,I have put a scrollView in this but i am facing an issue,when i open the soft keyboard entire layout shrinks as below screens,
[image: Keyboard compress login button and logo button]

**my code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="38dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    tools:context=".WelcomeActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLoginStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLoginStatusMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewLoginForm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FF4444" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editext"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/center_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editext"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg"
        android:text="@string/button_login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLike"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don&apos;t have an account?"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sing_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="forgotPassword"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#00c3b0" />
</LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                      android:gravity="center"
                       android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"

                     >
    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/forgotPass1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:gravity="center"
       android:visibility="invisible"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Forgot password?"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recovery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/forgotPass1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forgotPass1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/forgotPass1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="buttonRecoverPassword"
        android:text="Recover"
        android:textColor="#00c3b0"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         />
         </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on

Comment: @sasikumar - Not relavant to my question bro